# No Result when searching through an NSArray of NSDictionaries using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

Hey,
I have an Array of NSDictionaries (e.g. `[tempArray addObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:someArray forKeys:keys] autorelease]];` ) and when I try to search through it with NSPredicate it keeps giving me 'No Results'. (TempArray becomes self.patientList)

I have no compile-time warnings or errors, and if I `NSLog([self.filteredArray count]);` then it returns 0 as well.

Here is my relevant code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(first contains[cd] %@)", self.searchBar.text];
self.filteredArray = [self.patientList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
return [self.filteredArray count];
```

self.patientList and self.filteredArray are types NSMutableArray and NSArray respectively (changing self.filteredArray to NSMutableArray doesn't help).

I have tried using == instead of contains as well. Using `@"SELF contains[cd] %@"` only returns an item when the full item is typed (i.e. if the key 'name' is @"Bob" then if I type in Bob it will display it, but not when I type Bo or ob).

I'm really stumped on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently first is a reserved word when using predicates. From Apple's documentation:

> The following words are reserved:
>
> AND, OR, IN, NOT, ALL, ANY, SOME,
>   NONE, LIKE, CASEINSENSITIVE, CI,
>   MATCHES, CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH,
>   ENDSWITH, BETWEEN, NULL, NIL, SELF,
>   TRUE, YES, FALSE, NO, **FIRST**, LAST,
>   SIZE, ANYKEY, SUBQUERY, CAST,
>   TRUEPREDICATE, FALSEPREDICATE

Just change your key to something else, firstName perhaps, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just changed this and it worked. And just a question, how do you sort an array of dictionaries by one key? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. When it comes to sorting an array there are several methods available, all starting with sortedArray... . If you don't manage to find out how to do it just ask a new question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: `@Robert` But then how does it know which key to sort by? I'll have a look around though, thanks.

Comment: Ah yes I remember discovering this a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "like" instead:

```
first like[c] *%@*
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems correct.  So then:  do your dictionaries actually have a key called `first`?  And if they do, does it match the case exactly?

Comment: If I do `NSLog(@"%@",[[self.patientList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"first"]);` at the same place (numberOfRowsInSection:) then it gives 'Frederick'. The 'keys' array from above is ` NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first",@"last",@"address",@"number",nil] autorelease];`